# WP_query, meta_query NOT LIKE doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, content-management-system

My meta_query does not work, and I don't understand why. I have post status (archive) in a variable, and it won't display posts without this post status.

```
function getNewsListings($numberOfListings, $status) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => $numberOfListings,
        'meta_query'     => array(
                'key'        => 'post_status',
                'value'      => $status,
                'compare'    => 'NOT LIKE'
            )
    );
   $listings = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($listings->found_posts > 0 ) {
        echo '<ul id="news_list" style="list-style-type:none">';
        while ($listings->have_posts()) {
            $listings->the_post();
            $listItem = '<li id="news"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
            $listItem .= get_the_title() .'</a><hr></li>';
            echo $listItem;
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<p>No news found</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the "not work"? For a given input (eg "I have 7 posts of type news") What is the output you see? Which was the one you expected?

Comment: i see all posts with post_type="news" but i wont display posts where type news without post_status = $status

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to show the post that have post_type  **news**.

```
function getNewsListings($numberOfListings, $status) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => $numberOfListings,
       'post_status' => $status
    );
   $listings = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($listings->found_posts > 0 ) {
        echo '<ul id="news_list" style="list-style-type:none">';
        while ($listings->have_posts()) {
            $listings->the_post();
            $listItem = '<li id="news"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
            $listItem .= get_the_title() .'</a><hr></li>';
            echo $listItem;
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<p>No news found</p>';
    }
}
```